# change the image inside listview DataTemplate In WINRT

Tags: winrt-xaml, winrt-async

In windows app (WINRT)i want to change the image dynamically inside the listview,where the listview items are bind by datatemplate

Answer (score 0):

The image is part of your listviewitem template?  Could you add an image source path text property of your list items?  If you're updating the value dynamically your list items will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the PropertyChanged event when the value changes.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="{Binding imageSourcePath}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i want to change the image without reloading the list.for example using findcontrol in asp.net

Comment: <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid  Width="230" Height="70">
                                              <Image x:Name="imgdownload" Source="{Binding imgdownloadStatus}" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                                                        </Grid>                                                     
                                            </DataTemplate>

Comment: in this datatemplate i want to change image according to download status

Comment: You might look into the [ContainerContentChanging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.containercontentchanging.aspx) event of the list.  You can progressively populate your UI inside your DataTemplate as your data is loaded this way.

Comment: for example if i having 20 images in a list, I want to change only one image without loading the entire listview.

Comment: Yeah.  You'd build your item template to have an empty image and when you're ready to display it you can use CCC to set the Source of the item's image.  Only affects the single item, not the whole list.

Comment: I am not able to do.can you please share some example code.